# Meaning of SERVERPROPERTY ('ResourceLastUpdateDateTime')

Tags: sql-server

I have researched a while, a lot of articles name it and tell us to use it - but none really explains the meaning of the date and WHEN exactly it changes. Does anyone know?

Samples for articles not really explaining the meaning of this property:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190940.aspx
- http://www.mytechmantra.com/LearnSQLServer/How-to-Identify-the-Location-of-Resource-Database-in-SQL-Server/

Edit: The backstory behind the question simply does not exist. I just want to know what event forces this information to get a new timestamp. What makes the resource db getting updated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the BOL article you referenced to, the date is not going to change unless a Service Pack or CU creates new system objects. However the date returned may not necessarily coincide with the date you install that CU or SP.

> The Resource database makes upgrading to a new version of SQL Server
>   an easier and faster procedure. In earlier versions of SQL Server,
>   upgrading required dropping and creating system objects. Because the
>   Resource database file contains all system objects, an upgrade is now
>   accomplished *simply by copying the single Resource database file to
>   the local server*.

The only time you will notably see that value change is when you apply a service pack or upgrade SQL Server. It will likely change the same time you see the `ResourceVersion` value change. Which if I recall I only see the version number change with service packs.

I have an instance of SQL Server 2008 R2 that shows a build of `10.50.6220`, but the resource database shows `10.50.6000`. Which the date returned is `08/09/2014 13:40:43`, that is not when I applied the SP but probably the time frame that Microsoft's SQL Server Team finalized their testing. SP3 was released `09/26/2014`.

Comment: Sounds like it is not a very useful Information.